# How can I write the {{each}} view to the childViews in the parent view?

Tags: ember.js

I'm doing some animations where I'm catching events on the parent view and want to animate my childViews in a certain order. So I've ended up with something  like this:

**views/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({
  click: function(){
    console.log(this.childViews) // undefined :'(
  }
});
```

**views/post.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({});
```

My template:

```
{{#each post in content itemViewClass="post"}}
  <img {{bind-attr src=post.image}}">
{{/each}}
```

I don't quite understand how I can access the `post` views from my `index` view.

Answer (score 0):

The childViews property is for when you have child views. Your each block is not instantiating views so you don't have any child views, just a collection of img elements.

If you're not aware there is an excellent animation addon  for Ember by Edward Faulkner 
called [liquid-fire](https://github.com/ef4/liquid-fire).

The author also has a good [video presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4M78SO3gAc) on Ember animation as well.

I would recommend investigating that solution before trying to do your own as there are many life cycle concerns to take of.